# Object 'breaks' from falling

Tags: objective-c, ios8, sprite-kit, physics

I've made a square with x=25 & y= 25 and attached an SKPhysicsBody. I've made a standard platform level that has several tall drop areas. I want the the square to 'break'/suffer damage from falling from tall places. I looked at wikipedia and found Newton's law of universal gravitation F=mg. m is mass of the square & g is gravity. So I did this:

```
@implementation
{
    double m = square.physicsBody.mass;
    CGVector g = self.physicsWorld.gravity;
    double F;
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    [self fallFormula];
}

-(void)fallFormula
{
    F=m*g;
}
```

For a programmer, I'm exceptionally weak at math unfortunately. Can someone help with figuring out how to calculate force of impact upon the square's fall please? After that, I'll just figure out at what F value the square will 'break'. By the way, I only know objective-c (no Swift yet) and I'm using SpriteKit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to go all real life here why don't you just set your own velocity to damage rankings.

First declare a float. Then in the update method add this code:

```
if(myNode.physicsBody.velocity.dy < myFloat) {
    myFloat = myNode.physicsBody.velocity.dy;
}
```

Velocity.dy is vertical movement of a node's physicsBody. All you have to do now is set your damage rating based on the max dy velocity your node attains.

To test out how the dy values work you can this into your update method:

```
NSLog(@"dy velocity = %f",myNode.physicsBody.velocity.dy);
```

drop your node and look at the log.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to calculate the distance travelled by the object, which can be used to calculate the change in the potential energy. You can then get the force by making use of the relation between force and energy.

Answer (score 1):

I presume your squares are hitting a platform? If so the most realistic outcome would be to use [collision detection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW14) between the platform and the square.

When the platform and the square collide you will be given an [SKPhysicsContact](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContact/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKPhysicsContact) object which among other things gives you the "collisionImpulse" property which can tell you how hard your two objects hit each other.

Getting collisions working is a little bit of work, but it is worth figuring it out because it will save you from doing any math.

The collisionImpulse property could then be used for a minor break, or a major break. Pretty neat huh?